# is there a MacOS app or script to create a reorganized copy of my itunes music library

Tags: music, macos, itunes

When i look into the ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music folder, i see my music library organized by artist name like this:

```
./Artist-1/Album-BestOf-2016/Song-x.mp4a
./Artist-1/The-Album/Song-x.mp4a
./Artist-2/Album-BestOf-2016/Song-y.mp4a
./Compilations/Album-BestOf-2016/Song-x.mp4a
./Compilations/Album-BestOf-2016/Song-y.mp4a
```

i want a new folder where a copy of my music is organized by album name like this:

```
./Compilations/Album-BestOf-2016/Song-x.mp4a
./Compilations/Album-BestOf-2016/Song-y.mp4a
./Artist-1/The-Album/Song-x.mp4a
```

i would prefer when the new folder structure would only consist of symlinks pointing to the song in my itunes library. i will use this new folder  with a third-party app.

is there an app or script (free or commercial) to generate such a folder structure?

edit: changed the folder structure

Comment: What would you like the software to do if there is a clash due to two _or more_ different artists having released albums with the same title and possibly different tracks of the same name?

Comment: ok. i see the problem. there is no good solution.i change my desired folder structure to address this problem. basically what i want is to have only one copy of each track.